# Python, SQLITE 3, not such column

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I have a problem with some code I wrote:

```
def login(username, password):
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM masterPasswords WHERE passw='{}' AND user='{}'".format(password, username))
    if passw == password and user == username:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

This is the error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/fraze/Documents/GitHub/Password-Management/main.py", line 65, in <module>
    account()
  File "C:/Users/fraze/Documents/GitHub/Password-Management/main.py", line 28, in account
    tryLogin()
  File "C:/Users/fraze/Documents/GitHub/Password-Management/main.py", line 15, in tryLogin
    if am.login(usernameInput, masterPassInput) == usernameInput and masterPassInput:
  File "C:\Users\fraze\Documents\GitHub\Password-Management\accountManagement.py", line 19, in login
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM masterPasswords WHERE passw='{}' AND user='{}'".format(password, username))
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: passw
```

I need some help please...

Comment: First the query should be something like `c.execute("SELECT * FROM masterPasswords WHERE passw=? AND user=?", (password, username))` to parameterize it. But I don't know whether that will work because it's possible that you didn't build and table with a column called `passw`.

Comment: Yeah, obviously you table doesn't have a `passw` column. What is the question here?

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED: The error was that I changed the column names and the old (not changed) database had the older names and I was trying to access the new ones.